# ASP.NET Nav bar not displaying correctly in IE11

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm currently working on a web application for my company and ran into an issue. The navigation bar is displaying way bigger than it's supposed to, but only on IE11 or Edge. I've tested it with Chrome and it displays fine.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: 1]

I've checked the code on the master page and everything seems to be fine. Has anyone else ran into this issue? If so, is there a solution for this. I don't want to assume all users using the web application will be using Chrome.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="HotelReservation.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">Reservation Service</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">Delete</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <p class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">Hello, <asp:LoginName runat="server" />!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container body-content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET Application</p>
            </footer>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Site.CSS

```
/* Move down content because we have a fixed navbar that is 50px tall */
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Wrapping element */
/* Set some basic padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

/* Set widths on the form inputs since otherwise they're 100% wide */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}


/* Responsive: Portrait tablets and up */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .jumbotron {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .body-content {
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest posting your code so we can help you better

Comment: Hi Chris, I've attached the code for my Site.Master. If there's anything else you need please let me know :) Thanks!!!!

Comment: can you include the relevant styles?  This seems like a css issue

Comment: @maembe I've added the Site.CSS code to my post. I've kept the default configuration for this project. I havent added any styling or css to the site.